# Android ICS Compilation Issue

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I successfully Downloaded the source code for Android 4.0.3.
But I am unable to compile it on my machine.

My Machine configuration is UBUNTU 11.10 64 bit,4 GB RAM

When I am running the lunch command getting the following error.

```
/bin/bash: prebuilt/linux-x86/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.x/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: Permission denied
/bin/bash: prebuilt/linux-x86/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.x/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: Permission denied
/bin/bash: prebuilt/linux-x86/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.x/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: Permission denied
/bin/bash: build/core/find-jdk-tools-jar.sh: Permission denied
build/core/config.mk:268: *** Error: could not find jdk tools.jar, please install JDK6, which you can download from java.sun.com.  Stop.

** Don't have a product spec for: 'full'
** Do you have the right repo manifest?
```

JDK is already in a path.When I Run the Command java -version I am getting following OutPut

```
java version "1.6.0_26"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.1-b02, mixed mode)
```

Can Anyone Help to proceed?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you check the script build/core/find-jdk-tools-jar.sh, you can see that it first checks an environment variable called ANDROID_JAVA_HOME. If you set the ANDROID_JAVA_HOME environment variable to your JDK path, it should fix this error.

Comment: Something like this on osx: `export ANDROID_JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7)`

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by build/core/find-jdk-tools-jar.sh with wrong result for "which javac".

Usually, this is caused by javac is not configured as a alternative for system. So there is no link of /usr/bin/javac for your javac.

Please setup the alternative for javac:
$sudo update-alternatives  --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_32/bin/javac" 1

note: the installed directory of javac for me is "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_32/", you can change it by your configuration.

Comment: Thanks Man.But due to time constraint I moved to ubuntu 10.04.
I will check out your answer with ubuntu 11.10 machine and accordingly give you UpVote.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to run 32-bit binaries (the NDK toolchain) on a 64-bit OS, so first make sure you have the 32-bit compatibility libs installed:

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

If that doesn't solve it, then make sure you do have execute permission on those files.

Comment: I had installed ia32-libs still its shows the same error.
How do I add execute permission on those files.

Comment: Hi Graham I added the execution permission on file.
Now it shows only one error regarding java 

/bin/bash: build/core/find-jdk-tools-jar.sh: Permission denied
build/core/config.mk:268: *** Error: could not find jdk tools.jar, please install JDK6, which you can download from java.sun.com.  Stop.

** Don't have a product spec for: 'full'
** Do you have the right repo manifest?

Can you suggest me some trick how to remove it.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

-Open terminal
-type: chmod 777 WORKING_DIR -R
-this will fix the error