# Make cannot find tools.jar

Tags: java, path, makefile

Running Ubuntu 12.04

I have added to PATH: `/home/jeffrey/jdk1.6.0_43/lib`

I am attempting to build from source using Make:

```
make -j16
```

But encounter the error:

```
build/core/config.mk:268: *** Error: could not find jdk tools.jar, please install JDK6, which you can download from java.sun.com.  Stop.
```

Can anyone explain to me why Make cannot find `tools.jar`?

**EDIT**

```
JAVA_HOME=/home/jeffrey/jdk1.6.0_43/bin/java
```

Determined by entering `env` command into the shell.  Furthermore, this is set for all users in the `etc/profile`

Additionally:

```
jeffrey@jeffrey-Satellite-M645:~/WORKING_DIRECTORY$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_43"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_43-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.14-b01, mixed mode)
jeffrey@jeffrey-Satellite-M645:~/WORKING_DIRECTORY$
```

Comment: What are you trying make? The makefile probably assumes that the JDK can be found using the JAVA_HOME environment variable or something similar; it won't try to search PATH for tools.jar.

Comment: You don't point JAVA_HOME at a binary. You point it at the toplevel path where java is installed. Inversely you do point PATH at the location where the binaries live (not the binary itself though) and not at the toplevel directory of where java is installed.

Comment: @EtanReisner Per your comment I changed to `JAVA_HOME=/home/jeffrey/jdk1.6.0_43`.  Logged off/on - still not able to find tools.jar

Comment: Is there a tools.jar under that path somewhere?

Comment: Yes, in the lib folder.  Specifically in: `/home/jeffrey/jdk1.6.0_43/lib`

Comment: Simply setting a variable in your makefile or even in `/etc/profile` is not enough; that merely sets the variable for the local process (make or the shell).  You must `export` it, or the value is not passed to any commands that make or the shell might invoke (like `java`).  Try adding `export JAVA_HOME` to your makefile and/or `/etc/profile`.

Comment: I should also add: whenever trying to debug problems like this you should _always_ get it working by invoking the command from your shell command prompt first.  If you can't run it properly yourself, how do you expect make to do so?  Conversely, if you _can_ run it but `make` can't, then you know the issue is with your translation of the command into your makefile.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Setting the `ANDROID_JAVA_HOME` environment variable to JDK path, fixes this error.

I found the answer with [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10124522/android-ics-compilation-issue).

Comment: Well if you'd said up-front you were trying to build an Android environment, and/or used an "android" tag in your question, you may have had more relevant suggestions.  Given your question and tags everyone assumed you were trying to build a generic Java program.

Comment: @MadScientist I hindsight that is obvious, but I did not want to clutter the question with what I thought was irrelevant information.  It's a difficult balance with each situation on just how much to put into a question.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that JAVA_HOME env variable is set to jdk-install-dir

Answer (score 0):

Usually, this is caused by javac is not configured as a alternative for system. So there is no link of /usr/bin/javac for your javac.

Please setup the alternative for javac using the following command:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_32/bin/javac" 1
```

note: the installed directory of javac for me is "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_32/", you can change it by your configuration.